# Add ability to search for/sort answers by length

Tags: feature-request, jobs, search

This is probably specific to Careers, and there may be a better way to do it, but I'd like to be able to search/sort my own answers by the length of the response.

When adding questions to my SO Careers profile, I found that votes was not a very reliable way for me to find answers that I wanted to highlight.  Often highly voted answers tended to be short and/or for very simple, common questions.  For my careers page, I wanted to find answers that I had spent some time on, for hard questions, or that demonstrated my abilities in a positive way.  Short answers to common questions seem to be upvoted more often than lengthy answers to, perhaps, esoteric or difficult questions.

One heuristic for finding the types of answers that I am interested in is answer length.  I realize that I might be an outlier, but with over 5000 answers (167 pages), being able to sort or search using the answer length would be very handy.  Longer answers would contain either more code and/or more explanation and be an indication that I took more time on the answer.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/110081/

Comment: @balpha That's a great link. It could be useful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure as Ben pointed out in the comment you can do this through SEDE

http://data.stackexchange.com